# Populating empty string to a column of float type as "NULL" into MYSQL DB using python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I have an empty string stored in a variable. I would like to populate this empty string into a field of "Float" type as "NULL" using python. How can this be done?

```
if cols[6].get_text() == '':
        data['slp'] = (cols[6].get_text())
```

The above code populates 0 into the field with warnings in the console Data truncated for the column "slp" at row1 or Incorrect float value '' for column 'slp' at row1. I am using pymysql for connecting mysql and python.

Comment: What kind of object is `cols[6]`? You are missing some important information here. I suggest you add more information to the question to get this answered.

Comment: As for your problem: The mysql column must be `nullable` and the value given to `mysqldb` needs to be none.

Comment: Yeah None keyword in python works.

Comment: Normally written as `None`.